# Missing libkhtml5 library

Tags: shared-library

need your help. I am installing application KTECHLAB. After downloading the source code, I could compile and install the program successfully. However, when I run the program, it could not start at all due to missing file "libkhtml.so.5". This error is shown when I run the program via terminal. After doing internet search, I come to conclusion that  I need to install "libkhtml5" library. But the problem now is , I couldn't find which repository that contain the library. Please help how to solve this. Thank you.

Hendra